# Styling of php echo table th tags

Tags: html, forms, html-table, echo

I have echo table tags in multiple pages and I want to style the tr tag of tables by giving a class to echo tr tag and define css of the class in my css file. How can I do that? My view page code is here:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
 include('connection.php');
 $count=1;
 $result=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form")
 or die(mysql_error());
 echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
 echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Password</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Contact Number</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
  <tr>

<td align="center"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["fname"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["lname"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pwd"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["eml"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["num"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><a href="editrecord.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<td align="center"><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php $count++; } ?>
 }
 </table>";
  ?>
<p><a href="index.php">Add a new Record</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do it: assign the classes you want. Also do not echo html from php, cleaner way to keep it as html directly:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
 include('connection.php');
 $count=1;
 $result=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form")
 or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>
<tr class="class_i_choose"> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Password</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Contact Number</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>
 <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <tr class="a_class_from_my_css">

<td align="center"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["fname"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["lname"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pwd"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["eml"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["num"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><a href="editrecord.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<td align="center"><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php $count++; } ?>
 }
 </table>";
  ?>
<p><a href="index.php">Add a new Record</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [I pulled for ya here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506801/styling-of-php-echo-table-th-tags#comment87062255_49506801), but the OP doesn't seem to know how things work here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner looks like one of those that are not interested in how this site works but only in someone to do the job for them :-)

Comment: We run into those ever so often. Oh well, *c'est la vie* I guess.